# ID not passing causing Laravel 5.2 to error "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting the following error code

> Creating default object from empty value

When I dump the $post it returns null, however when I dump $id it returns the ID.

The controller code is as follows:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $this->validate($request, array (
            'post' => '',
            'mailbox' => '',
            'conum' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'telans' => '',
            'TC' => 'required',

        ));

        //store
        $post = Customers::find($id);

        dd($id);

        $post->post = $request->input('post');
        $post->postpro = $request->input('mailbox');
        $post->telans = $request->input('telans');
        $post->conum = $request->input('conum');
        $post->prefix = $request->inut('prefix');
        $post->tc = $request->input('TC');

        //save
        $post->save();

        //session flash message
        //Session::flash('success','This customer has now been added');

        //redirect
return redirect('/home');}
```

The form in the index file is as follows

```
{!! Form::model('Customers', ['route'=>['products.update', Auth::user()->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

 {{ Form::hidden('business', Auth::user()->name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','maxlength'=>'255'))}}


    {{ Form::label('post', 'Mailbox')}}
    {{ Form::checkbox('post',1, 0, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        <div id="extra_form">
        {{ Form::label('mailbox', 'Mailbox Option')}}</br>
        {{ Form::select('mailbox', array('rolling' => 'Rolling','month' => 'Monthly','year' => 'Yearly'), 'null', array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        </div>
    {{ Form::label('conum', 'Company Number')}}
    {{ Form::checkbox('conum',1, 0, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        <div id="extra_form1">   
        {{ Form::label('prefix', 'Preferred number prefix')}}
        {{ Form::tel('prefix', 0, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        </div>
    {{ Form::label('telans', 'Telephone Answering')}}
    {{ Form::checkbox('telans',1, 0, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
        <hr>
        <div id="extra_form3">
            {{ Form::label('posttc', 'Mailbox Terms and Conditions')}}</br>
            Click here
        </div>
        <div id="extra_form2">
            {{ Form::label('conumtc', 'Company Number Terms and Conditions')}}</br>
            Click here
        </div>
        <div id="extra_form4">
            {{ Form::label('telanstc', 'Telephone Answering Terms and Conditions')}}</br>
            Click here
        </div>-->
    {{ Form::label('TC', 'I accept the Office Flex terms and conditions.')}}
    {{ Form::checkbox('TC',1, 0, array('class' => 'form-control','required'=>''))}}
    {{ Form::submit('Select Product', array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'create_btn'))}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Are u sure u've customers with ```id``` you're passing?

Comment: Thats the reason, thank you! Was Auth id was coming from the users table! Cant believe I didnt see that.

Comment: check your Auth::user() . . dd it.. may be its the issue. your Auth::user may be null and as its trying to get ->id from it error throws saying that you are trying to get property from null.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to make sure the correct table ID was being added.

```
 $id = DB::table('customers')->where('business', Auth::user()->name)->pluck('id');
    $iid=implode($id);
```